# Multicast networking app with Windows Phone 8 emulator

Tags: networking, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, multicast

I'm implementing a multiplayer card game for windows phone 8 using multicast networking.
However, when I try to link a windows phone and the emulator nothing happens (no errors as well).

I can surf the web using internet explorer so my emulator is connected to the internet.

Do I have to make a special operation on the emulator in order to enable it to do multicast operations? 
Or is there something missing in the code?

Here is the code:

Initialization

```
channel = new UdpChannel(IPAddress.Parse("224.109.108.106"), 3000);

this.channel.OnAfterOpened += new EventHandler<UdpPacketEventArgs>(channel_OnAfterOpen);

this.channel.OnPacketReceived += new EventHandler<UdpPacketEventArgs(Channel_PacketReceived);

this.channel.Open();
```

My multicast operating class:

```
public UdpChannel(IPAddress address, int port)
    {
        groupAddress = address;
        localPort = port;
        client = new UdpAnySourceMulticastClient(groupAddress, localPort);
    }

    public void Open()
    {
        if (!isJoined)
        {
            this.client.BeginJoinGroup(
                result =>
                {
                    try
                    {
                        this.client.EndJoinGroup(result);
                        isJoined = true;
                        this.AfterOpened();
                        this.Receive();
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        throw e;
                    }
                }, null);
        }
    }

    private void AfterOpened()
    {
        EventHandler<UdpPacketEventArgs> handler = this.OnAfterOpened;

        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new UdpPacketEventArgs(string.Empty, string.Empty));
    }

    private void Receive()
    {
        if (isJoined)
        {
            Array.Clear(this.buffer, 0, this.buffer.Length);
            this.client.BeginReceiveFromGroup(this.buffer, 0, this.buffer.Length, result =>
            {
                if (!isDisposed)
                {
                    IPEndPoint source;
                    try
                    {
                        this.client.EndReceiveFromGroup(result, out source);
                        this.AfterReceived(source, this.buffer);
                        this.Receive();
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        isJoined = false;
                        this.Open();
                    }
                }
            }, null);
        }
    }

    public void SendTo(int cardId)
    {
        byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(cardId.ToString());
        if (isJoined)
        {
            this.client.BeginSendToGroup(data, 0, data.Length,
                result =>
                {
                    this.client.EndSendToGroup(result);

                }, null);
        }
    }

    private void AfterReceived(IPEndPoint source, byte[] p)
    {
        EventHandler<UdpPacketEventArgs> handler = this.OnPacketReceived;

        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new UdpPacketEventArgs(source.Address.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8.GetString(p, 0, p.Length)));
    }

    private void BeforeClose()
    {
        EventHandler<UdpPacketEventArgs> handler = this.OnBeforeClosing;

        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new UdpPacketEventArgs(string.Empty, string.Empty));
    }

    #region IDisposable

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (!isDisposed)
        {
            Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }
        isDisposed = true;
    }

    ~UdpChannel()
    {
        Dispose(false);
    }

    private void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            client.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

My events

```
public class UdpPacketEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public string Message { get; private set; }
    public string Source { get; private set; }

    public UdpPacketEventArgs(string source, string data)
    {
        this.Message = data;
        this.Source = source;
    }
}
```

My events handlers

```
private void Channel_PacketReceived(object sender, UdpPacketEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Something Received");
}

private void channel_OnAfterOpen(object sender, UdpPacketEventArgs e)
{
    this.Status.Text = "Connected";
}
```

Comment: There are two good samples: [1](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Multicast-Sockets-Sample-51190c11) and [2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh286407(v=vs.105).aspx) - do you seen them?